# Odds in favor/against that the first person to receive a gift is female

Tags: probability

At a conference $60\%$ of the people in attendance were female. At the end of the conference each person is given a gift.  The first person is chosen at random.

a) Determine the odds in favor of that person being female

b) Determine the odds against that person being female.

I don't even now where to start.

Comment: You just need to convert the percentage to odds. The 'odds in favor' is the ratio of the number of 'successes' (which in this case is being female) and the number of 'failures'. So, suppose you have 100 people at this conference. Then you know 60 are female and 40 are male. So then the odds in favor are 60 to 40 ... which we write as 60:40 ... and can be simplified to 3:2.

Comment: Are you sure this is Grade 12 Math?

Comment: Are you sure of your vocabulary?  "odds" and "probability" are not the same numerically.  If you toss a fair coin, the probability that it comes up $H$ is $\frac 12$.  The odds that it comes up $H$ are $1:1$.  Which did you mean?

Comment: @Grade 12 Math Help, check the check mark?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am right, so correct me if I'm wrong.

---

So assume that there are 100 persons at the conference. Therefore, 60 people there are female, and 40 people there are male.

Recall that odds are $\frac{\text{Number of possible things}}{\text{Number of things not possible}}$.

a)Determine the odds in favor of that person being female. We plug numbers into our "odds" formula getting  $\frac{60}{40}=\frac{6}{4}=\boxed{\frac{3}{2}}$

b)Determine the odds against that person being female. So this time, we are wanting to calculate the exact opposite of what we calculated in part a. Therefore we see that the answer is $\frac{40}{60}=\frac{4}{6}=\boxed{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: Anyone clarrify? Or if I'm right, mark my answer as right?

Comment: @Grade 12 Math Help, check the check mark?